# How many objects does constructor create in inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have 2 concrete empty classes: A and B. Class B is a subclass of Class A. I think there is only one heap object created when running the B constructor.

However, Igor [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3359363/10201089) in an answer that C# inherited classes are similar to C++'s. AFAIK in C++ inheritance, every class should create an object of its type, so why did he mean that in C#, 2 heap objects would be created, 1 for A class and 1 for B class?

Comment: Have a read of the link you provided. Read the second comment on it. It **directly** answers your question.

Comment: `so why did he mean that in C#, 2 heap objects would be created, 1 for A class and 1 for B class?` His answer does not say that. What it **does** say is that two objects were created - **because `new` was called twice**. Whether it was for `ClassA` or `ClassB` is irrelevant.

Comment: New objects are created when you use keyword `new`.